# Operation on data read from a file

Tags: python-2.7

The following operation returns -0.20 which is fine:

```
a=[1.,5]
x=a[0]
y=a[1]
z=(-1*x)/(x*y)
print ("{0:.2f}".format(z))
```

However, as soon as I read the **same data** from a file it doesn't work. Why?
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

```
my_file=open("tmp.txt")  
for lines in my_file:  
    x=lines.split()  
    x0=x[0]  
    x1=x[1]  
print x0,x1  
y=(-1*x1)/(x0+x1)
```

Comment: Worth noting that your error message tells you exactly what's wrong: you're trying to divide two strings

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the variables to integers:

```
x0 = int(x[0])
x1 = int(x[1])
```

In addition, the loop resets the variables `x0` and `x1` each loop, so the value of `y` will be based only on the last line.

Comment: Casting the variables resolve the error.  Thank  you.